# How to disable DOI/URL for bibtex in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, bibtex, csl

I am using better bibtex and zotero to generate references in rmarkdown.

It works very good except that journal articles and books have an url/doi associated.

My adviser is not too happy about it and I could not figure out how to disable the url/doi in the rmarkdown config or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

What I know is that you have to edit your *.csl file (asa.csl, apa.csl or something you use). You could accomplish this very easy by uploading it to [this online csl editor](http://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/). Browse to `bibliography/layout/access(macro)/Group/conditional/` and look if there is an `URL` entry. I got rid of the DOI by setting an option there that the variable should be 'url' AND the document type 'webpage'. Then download the new *csl file, save it to your prefered directory and just knit it. (Look also [here with pictures](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/csl-editor/05-example-removing-doi)).

*Note:* Please make rather a safety copy before messing around with your *csl.